# Google Chart adding 3 or more tables in one chart

Tags: google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have 3 tables that I want to draw in one chart , how could I do this? I tried Join method but it only works with two tables? I was thinking to use group by its not working for some reason , please see the code below

```
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Jan');

data1.addRows([
    [1, 0.48],
    [2, 0.66],
    [5, 0.55],
    [6, 0.28],
    [8, 0.332],
    [9, 0.625],
    [10, 0.5],
    [12, 0.34],
    [13, 0.668]
]);

var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data2.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
data2.addColumn('number', 'Feb');

data2.addRows([
    [1, 0.77],
    [2, 0.88],
    [5, 0.55],
    [6, 0.36],
    [8, 0.798],
    [9, 0.625],
    [10, 0.885],
    [12, 0.34],
    [13, 0.48]
]);

    var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data3.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
data3.addColumn('number', 'Mar');

data3.addRows([
    [1, 0.43],
    [2, 0.76],
    [5, 0.98],
    [6, 0.32],
    [8, 0.123],
    [9, 0.455],
    [10, 0.78],
    [12, 0.90],
    [13, 0.48]
]);
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: how should the resulting table look like?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to join, just more columns...

```
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Jan');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Feb');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Mar');

data1.addRows([
    [1, 0.48, 0.77, 0.43],
    [2, 0.66, 0.88, 0.76],
    [5, 0.55, 0.55, 0.98],
    [6, 0.28, 0.36, 0.32],
    [8, 0.332, 0.798, 0.123],
    [9, 0.625, 0.625, 0.455],
    [10, 0.5, 0.885, 0.78],
    [12, 0.34, 0.34, 0.90],
    [13, 0.668, 0.48, 0.48]
]);
```